# How to undelete or restore deleted all

Tags: appexchange

I have installed free app from appexchange..but I deleted app.now I want to get back app again.what to do .where to restore the app .

Comment: You can install the app again. Not sure about the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to restore/undelete a deleted app. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000MLWGIA4 
You might be able to install in from appExchange again.

But data in the app is more difficult.

You can also try and contact Customer Support. 
Best regards, 
Christian